# Open Facebook app when trying to login

Tags: facebook, react-native, react-native-fbsdk

I am using react-native-fbsdk and when I try to login it opens Safari in IOS (not tested on Android), but I want it to open Facebook app if it is installed on device.

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

if the facebook app is installed on your device , then the package will directly use it , no need to add something on your code unless you did not installed the react-native-fbsdk properly , in my case , it's working using the app .

Comment: Thanks for an answer. Here what I found: as per https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2015/10/29/Facebook-Login-iOS9/ documentation in apps that use the newest SDK (v4.6 and v3.24), we will surface a flow using Safari View Controller (SVC) instead of fast-app-switching (FAS) because of additional dialog interstitials that add extra steps to the login process in FAS on iOS 9. Additionally, data that we've seen from more than 250 apps indicate that this is the best experience for people in the long run.

Comment: Their is setLoginBehavior prop for LoginManager from rn-fbsdk, but even in that package documentation it is mentioned that if you even mention native as login behavior the SDK may still use Safari instead (native means use FB app if it is installed).